# Is the linear map unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Given $T_3: \mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^{2×2}$ with $T_3(1,2,3) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\  1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$, $T_3(4,5,6) = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 3 \\2 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$, $T_3(2,1,0) = \begin{bmatrix} -5 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, is $T_3$ unique?

I did not find anywhere the definition of unique linear map. What is a unique linear map and how can see if a linear map is uique?

Comment: There’s no special meaning to this phrase. The map is unique if it’s the only one that satisfies the given conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three given input vectors to $T_3$ are linearly *dependent*:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1&2&3\\4&5&6\\2&1&0\end{vmatrix}=0$$
Indeed, we see that $T_3(4,5,6)-2T_3(1,2,3)=T_3(2,1,0)$, so only two linearly independent points of $T_3$ have been specified, whereas three are required for its uniqueness. $T_3$ is not the unique map with the given points.

Comment: So a linear map is unique  if it is either bijective or injective but not only surjective?

Comment: @LuaiGhunim Yes.